# How can I sort result of all adcreatives under an adaccount by creation date?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ads, facebook-marketing-api, ads-api

I'm using below facebook marketing API to fetch all ad creatives under an adaccount,

`https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/{{adaccount_id}}/adcreatives`

Can anyone suggest which parameter/field I can use to sort results by ascending order of creation date of particular adcreative?

Comment: Unless the documentation for a particular endpoint specifically mentions a parameter that can be used for sorting, it usually means there isn't one.

Comment: Yeah, there are no such parameters which can be used for sorting, thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't. What can you do instead is to fetch `AdCreatives` via `Ad` and because the creative is associated to the `Ad`, you can then sort by the `created_time` field.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Sprizgola, the only concern is there might be some creatives that are created but not used in any ads, those we might miss in this solution.